# how to detect garbage string value in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex, ios9

I am facing one issue related some garbage value,

In database it shows like below image : (SQLiteManager)
[image]

After putting debug mode it shows like :

[image]

And when i am printing this object, it will print some unreadable string.
[image]

So how can i detect this value??
I need to identify it, Please help me.

**EDIT**
It seems like hexadecimal characters in it, can anybody tell how can i detect or remove from the string?

Comment: You can detect it by checking the characters of the string (`characterAtIndex`).  How you validate them depends on what you consider valid, which is something we can't answer for you.

Comment: @Avi: thanks for quick responce, actually i am stuck at same , what should i consider that it is a correct string?

Comment: @Avi: How can i use (characterAtIndex) ?? How much length?

Comment: It may be worth figuring out where the bad data is coming from.

Comment: Why dont convert into string and then print?, Something like, (NSStirng *)model->_lastUpdatedBy:

Comment: What do you mean by how much length?  `characterAtIndex` returns a single character.

Comment: @Avi: If it is normal string what  characterAtIndex  will return?

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal: It gives unreadble value. some blank values.

Comment: It returns the character, as a unichar.  Why don't you read the documentation?

Comment: I think it is HEX chars. can anyone tell how to remove hexadecimal characters from string?

Comment: You can use characterSets to find out if your input is valid or not. E.g. you may create a character set of all alphanumeric characters [a-z0-9A-Z], trim the string with it, if the length of trimmed string is greater than 0, then it contains invalid values.

Comment: @NSNoob: 
it is possible that some special chars are available in name like(_,~,.,etc), is there any way to use this in chars range with alphanumeric ??

Comment: @NetDemo we most certainly can. See the modified answer