# How to remove hexadecimal characters from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex

I am facing one issue related some hexa value in string, i need to remove hexadecimal characters from NSString.

The problem is when i print object it prints as "BLANK line". And in debug mode it shows like :[image]

So how can i remove it from the string?

**EDIT**

Triming whitespace :
[image]

result of NSLog is :

**2015-12-14 15:37:10.710 MyApp [2731:82236] tmp :''**

Database:

[image]

Earlier question: 
[how to detect garbage string value in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34263427/3793501)

Comment: [This](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) will be helpful

Comment: why negative rep, if you cant able to give answer.?

Comment: model.lastupdatedby is it string?

Comment: yes, but show like some taggedpointer string

Comment: @NetDemo Can you share how you are creating that string? I think you are making a copy of some other string

Comment: @NSNoob: I don't know, Actually i am fetching data from database, I think when i am strong data in DB , it may be store in DB.
I am attching DB screenshot.

Comment: can you add the result of NSLog ? Maybe you can use NSRegularExpression to get what you want from a string

Comment: It is an interesting question. It will be very helpful if you add the code where you populate `model`.

Comment: @enzo : NSlog result is added. and can you give some NSRegularExpression example for removing hex values.?

Comment: @NSNoob: Yes, this is strange.

Comment: It appears during the population, it picks up that garbage data from your DB and becomes a subclass of NSString which is NSTaggedPointerString. Your column LAST_UPDATED has garbage values in it

Comment: @NSNoob: Ya i think you are correct. 
but now problems how can i remove or detect it?

Comment: @NetDemo I answered it on your earlier question

Comment: @NSNoob: Thanks It works, You can put answer in this question also, i'll accept it.

Comment: @NetDemo thats great I will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your dataset clearly has garbage values, You can use this method to check if your string is valid or not. Define your validation criteria and simply don't entertain the values which are garbage. But as suggested before by gnasher, you should rather look for the bug which is causing insertion of garbage data in your database. Once you have done that, check if the input string matches your defined criteria. If it does, do what you want. If it doesn't, simply move on.

```
-(BOOL) isValidString: (NSString*) input
{
         NSMutableCharacterSet *validSpecialChars = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_~.,"];//Add your desired characters here
         [validSpecialChars formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
         return [[input stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:validSpecialChars] isEqualToString:@""];
}
```

If your string will contain only your defined characters, it will return true. If it contains any other characters (garbage or invalid) it will return false.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but if you want to remove all the control characters then

```
string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]
```

If you need to be faster and are sure the control characters are only at the beginning and ending of a string then

```
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];
```

NOTE: Removing all control characters will remove all new lines (`\n`)!

---

From [NSCharacterSet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/controlCharacterSet):

> These characters are specifically the Unicode values U+0000 to U+001F and U+007F to U+009F.

The value you are having a problem with is `\x06` which is [`U+0006`](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0006).

---

If you want to remove just `\x06`, then you can always create a characters set just for it.

```
NSCharacterSet *hex6 = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\x06"];
string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:hex6] componentsJoinedByString:@""]
```

Comment: Hi Jeffery , are "\x06" control character?
i dont know other controlCharecters so ..

Answer (score 1):

First, don't trust the Xcode debugger. Print characterAtIndex:0 to be sure that you really have what you think you have.

Second, deleting stuff is all good and well, but you are doctoring around with a symptom. You should really try to figure out where the contents of _lastUpdatedBy comes from and why it is what it is. You might have a serious bug here and trying to cover it up. For example, there might be a bug that stores rubbish data instead of the correct data, and you are just covering up for that bug.

Comment: You are right. I need to check from where this value is getting inserted wrong. I'll check it. Thnks :)